# Central finite difference coefficients Python

Tags: python

By using this equation:
[second order Central finite difference coefficients equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x946m.png)

I need to find the coefficients given it for a second order differential. Without using a library that will just do it for me.
[Central finite difference coefficients table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O2nE.png)

I tried using nested for loops to get each number but for some reason it never went to one of my elif sections.I have print values there to check when it does go there and what values the variables are.

I am not getting any error just the incorrect numbers.

```
"""
Filter for 2nd derivative
"""
n = 2
k = n/2
#k = range(-k,k+1)
#k = list(k)
h = 0.01


for j in range(0, n+1):
    Isum = 0
    
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        Msum = 0
        if i == j:
            continue
        else:
            
            for m in range(0, n+1):
                product = 1
                if m == j or m == i:
                    continue
                else:
                    
                    for l in range(0, n+1):
                        if l == j or l == i or l == m:
                            continue
                            print("j is equal to:", + j)
                            print("i is equal to:", + l)
                            print("j - i is equal to:", + j - l)
                        product = product * ((k-l)/j-l)    
                product = product * (1/(j - m))
                Msum += product
        Msum = Msum * (1/(j-i))
        Isum += Msum
print(Isum)
```

Comment: Could you post the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: You should avoid constructs such as `if i == j: continue else: ...`.  Do instead `if i != j: ...`. Otherwise, just remove the `else:` and unindent all statements inside the `else`.  This is equivalent and much more readable.

Comment: By looking at the formula there should be three nested loops (not 4 as in your code). Where does `j` comes from?

Comment: There is a first bug in `product = product * ((k-l)/j-l)`. It should be `product = product * ((k-l)/(j-l))`